# Where does Stack Exchange take its PHP syntax highlighter from?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I know Stack Exchange uses Google Code Prettify, but I can't find the PHP highlighter outside Stack Exchange.

This gives me a 404 error:
https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/lang-php.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no separate PHP extension, `prettify.js` handles PHP natively. From the [README](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html):

> #### For which languages does it work?
>
> The comments in prettify.js are authoritative **but the lexer should work on a number of languages**
>    including C and friends, Java, Python, Bash, SQL, HTML, XML, CSS, Javascript, Makefiles, and Rust. **It works passably on** Ruby, **PHP**, VB, and Awk and a decent subset of Perl and Ruby, but, because of commenting conventions, but doesn't work on Smalltalk.
>
> Other languages are supported via extensions:
>
> [snip table of extra languages]

Emphasis mine.

Comment: You are right! I'm surprised that can't be found at the Wiki page